# Best way to convert "locationInNode:self" after being deprecated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I used to have some code, that, in short did

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
}
```

Unfortunately it seems that `locationInNode` has been deprecated, since it doesn't work anymore. I'm trying to finish a game I started a few months ago, so it would be nice to have a quick easy solution that gives the same point as before. I tried using `touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view]`, but unfortunately that gives the point in the current view, and the Node I am using is smaller than the whole view. Sorry this is kind of a noob question, but I'm getting back into it and haven't been able to find the answer elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: locationInNode must have been a custom method, in cocos2d there is this: http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/Classes/CCNode.html#//api/name/convertToNodeSpace:

Comment: Look into UITouch+CC.h the locationInNode: method is still there if you work with UITouch objects so the above code is supposed to work.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I have to manually add it for some reason, I'll double check if that .h file is still in my project